# element insertBefore isn't inserted

Tags: javascript

I want to use insertBefore but the element isn't inserted before here the code:

```
if(width <= 450) {
  var addThis = document.querySelector('.socialShare');
  var readMore = document.querySelector('.read-more-wrap');

  document.querySelector('.blog-detail').insertBefore(addThis, readMore); 
}
```

and here the html structure :

[image]

How can I insert that specific element before `.read-more-wrap`

Comment: Please next time click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use their parent with [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), e.g.

```
parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)
```

which in this case appears to be `main`

```
if(width <= 450) {
  var addThis = document.querySelector('.socialShare');
  var readMore = document.querySelector('.read-more-wrap');

  //document.querySelector('.blog-detail').insertBefore(addThis, readMore); 
  document.querySelector('.blog-detail main').insertBefore(addThis, readMore); 
}
```